# Debian - Disaster recovery software

Tags: linux, backup, debian, disaster-recovery

I run a web server on Debian-Lenny.

For the moment, I backup my whole system with **tar** with a daily script.

But for the recovery, I need to reinstall a clean Debian and then untar my latest tar file into the clean Debian and then I get my working system back.

Now, I would like to use a software like Ghost to backup my system daily.

If my system crashes, what I want is an usb key that I insert into my server with the latest image backed up from my server and I want to be up and running again.

Comment: You shouldn't really have do a base install, just building a partition table, and creating the filesystems should be enough.  A tar gives you a lot of flexibility.  Perhaps you just need to take a full image of the base system after the install is done, and then restore your data?

Comment: BTW, are you expecting some down-time when the backup image is being taken, or did you want that to happen while the server was online?

Comment: I take my backup while my server is live (online). With tar.

Answer (score 1):

If your have setup your system with a [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_volume_management) you could make a snapshot and then create an image of your disk which you can than backup and with a saved partition table you have everything you need to restore your server on a new disc or even a new machine. The LVM snapshot allows you to backup your data to a specific time without your backup been mixed up with data that has changed since you started your backup.

Comment: This works even better if you just Xen Dom0 with one or two DomU's on lvm volumes. Live snapshot of the running DomU and do what every you want it!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem? If you have ghost infrastructure, by all means use it. In the *nix world, we prefer things like dd and dump/restore.

You could also use PXE for system roll-out and a file server to store your system images on is a must-have.

Using a USB flash drive seems a bit desperate :-)

Comment: Yeah, I think I will drop the idea of using a USB drive, héhé!